# Check for DbNull in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am finding difficulties in validating the following

```
if(personDS.person[0].IdFk!= DBNull.Value)
```

this is the compile time error - cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid and 'System.Dbnull'

Comment: Exception is thrown when you try to access IdFk because it's not nullable.

Comment: You might find the answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/211436/nullable-guid Nullable GUID question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should check:

```
if(personDS.person[0].IsIdFkNull())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check against an empty Guid

```
if (personDS.person[0].IdFk == Guid.Empty )
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(!(personDS.person[0].IdFk is System.DBNull))
```

Comment: If IdFk is null, it will throw exception. Check DataSet autogenerated class for implementation. The property throws and exception. Maybe it's can be changed by column property, but it's not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Id is a Guid, which is a Value type and will therefore never equal DBNull.Value. Before I can fully help, I will need to know the types of `personDS` (DataSet maybe?) and `person` (DataTable maybe). Assuming so, then maybe:

```
if (!personDS.person[0].IsNull("IdFK"))
```

If `person` is not a DataTable but a class then check for either `IdFk == Guid.Empty`, if `IdFk` is a Guid, or `IdFk == null` if `IdFk` is `Guid?`.

Answer (score 0):

Is IdFk declared as nullable ? 
Es:

```
public Guid? Idfk
```

If so you can :

```
if(personDS.person[0].IdFk.HasValue)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this is complete nonsense, for the followingg reasons: 1) `public` starts with a lower `p` 2) the `?` suffix has to be appended to the type, not the identifier 3) if `personDS.person[0].IdFK` indeed is null the code will throw an `InvalidOperationException`, else the condition will always be false, since `DBNull.Value` doesn't equal anything but itself and a `Guid` can never be of type DBNull (and it won't compile, since you can't compare `Guid` and `DBNull` without casting either one to object, which will do a reference comparison)

Comment: True, I without VS now and coding in vb this period. Made a some confusion :)  Edited the response anyway, thanks.